# Unity2D. Добавление в список спавнящихся объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d, list

У меня спавнятся блоки, в рандомном количестве:

```
public GameObject TopLineBlock;

float rand = getSpawnPosX();
previousBlockPosX += rand;
spawnPosition = new Vector2(previousBlockPosX, topBlockY);
Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
Instantiate(TopLineBlock, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
```

Как добавить эти блоки в список, или любую другую структуру, чтобы можно было обойти их в цикле?
Чтобы как только создавался блок - он попадал в этот список. А при удалении этого блока - удалялся из списка.

Comment: List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();

(...)

List.Add(Instantiate(TopLineBlock, spawnPosition, spawnRotation));

Answer (score 1):

```
List<GameObject> ListTLB = new List<GameObject>();
public GameObject TopLineBlock;

void Spawn () {
    float rand = getSpawnPosX();
    previousBlockPosX += rand;
    spawnPosition = new Vector2(previousBlockPosX, topBlockY);
    Quaternion spawnRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    GameObject NewTLB = Instantiate(TopLineBlock, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
    NewTLB.AddComponent<AutoAddRemove>().SetList(ListTLB);
}
```

---

```
public class AutoAddRemove : MonoBehaviour {
    List<GameObject> ListTLB;

    public void SetList (List<GameObject> list) {
        ListTLB = list;
        ListTLB.Add(gameObject);
    }

    void OnDestroy () {
        ListTLB.Remove(gameObject);
    }
}
```